# How do I copy rows in excel with VBA and retain XML mapping?

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I am trying to translate data on CSV files to XML.

I have an XML file I created mapped as source to an excel spreadsheet, and doing manual exports has worked fine, however when attempting to copy the initial row of the XML mapping to create another record, the XML mapping is lost, so when I export the workbook, only the first row is translated to XML while the remaining rows are ignored.

[image]

Here is the code I am using to copy the initial row in excel:

```
Range("A3:AE3").Select
Selection.Copy
Range(xsku & ":" & xsku).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Copy and pasting the initial row manually retains the XML mapping, however when I try to record a macro of my actions to view the code, the macro is empty.

Comment: Shouldn't you be working with the `.DataBodyRange` of the ListObject table?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with that command, the MSDN documentation on XmlMaps never mentioned it. I'll have a look at how to use it to see if it's for me. Where did you come across that command?

Comment: I managed to find a solution: Changing the following line in the above example to "Paste:=xlPasteFormats" kept the XML mapping, however doing further testing, I'm unable to clear the XML mapping with Selection.Clear, and Selection.Delete throws an error that I am shifting cells off the worksheet. Any ideas?